# Tokens in Nested macros and ##

Tags: c, macros

From The C Programming Language, by KRC(page 231)

> After
>
> ```
> #define cat(x, y)       x ## y
> ```
>
> the call `cat(var,  123)` yields `var123`. However, the call 
>   `cat(cat(1,2),3)` is undefined: the presence of `##` prevents the
>   arguments of the outer call from being expanded. Thus it produces the
>   token string `cat  (  1  ,  2  )3` and `)3` (the catenation of the
>   last token of the first argument with the first token of the second)
>   is not a legal token.

I don't understand the statement:"(the catenation of the last token of the first argument with the first token of the second)".
What is  "the last token of the first argument" and what is "the first token of the second"?
Maybe there is a mistake in K&R and it should be written as :"Thus it produces the token string  cat  (  1  ,  2 and )3 (the catenation of the last token of the first argument with the first token of the second) is not a legal token."
Am I right?

Comment: Thus **{** it produces the token string `cat`  `(`  `1`  `,`  `2`  `)3` **}** and **{** `)3` (the catenation of the last token of the first argument with the first token of the second) is not a legal token **}**. (A comma before *and* may have made the meaning more clear, but many style guides prohibit commas before *and*.)

Comment: why )3 is not a legal token?

Comment: For anyone looking how to solve the problem (not just understanding it), use second level expansion: `#define cat_internal(x, y) x ## y` and `#define cat(x, y) cat_internal(x, y)`, then use `cat(cat(1, 2), 3)`

Comment: @Victor `cat(1, 2)3` might be a valid token in the preprocessor phase, but not in the compiler phase after the preprocessor finished its work.

Comment: @grek40
why not?

Comment: @Victor show me any valid C code that contains `)3` without the `)` being part of a preprocessor macro. Or show me the part of the C syntax definition that suggests this may be allowed. Unless you provide such thing, I surely won't waste my time on a simple *"why not?"*

Comment: `)3` is not a legal token in the C language. It's not an identifier (doesn't start with a letter), not a number (doesn't start with a digit) and not an operator. In fact the only legal token in C which begins with `)` is `)`.

Comment: @grek40 `cat(1, 2)3` is not a valid preprocessing token.

Comment: @HWalters I'm not sure about the formal syntax, but if I write `#define Test cat(cat(1, 2), 3)4` in VS, then I can use `Test` as `1234` in code as long as `cat` is defined as second level expansion as I commented before.

Comment: @HWalters So eigher the preprocessor that is shipped with Visual Studio is not following the standard or `)3` is a legal combination of characters in some preprocessor context (though it might be separate tokens that just happen to come without a separating character)

Comment: @grek40 According to the standard in 6.10.3.3 p3, describing the result of the paste operator: "If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined."  That is definitive; how Visual Studio behaves is not.  Visual Studio happens to choose to ignore pastes that don't result in valid preprocessor tokens.

Comment: @HWalters I don't see how this is relevant for my presented code. The result of `cat( ... )` would be a valid preprocessing token as far as I can tell. It just so happens to be merged with a number that follows right after the closing parenthesis of this preprocessor macro.

Comment: Most comments moved to the answer; in the specific case of Visual Studio, it chooses a behavior in this undefined case--to ignore the issue.  That leaves `cat(1,2)3`, which is then expanded during the final evaluation stage (rescanning and replacement).  But you can't say that because something "works" in VS means it's valid C.

Comment: @HWalters I know that implementation support doesn't replace a standard, but at least I was able to construct a combination with more macros, where the `cat(1,2)3` was accepted by all compilers I tried (online compilers in different versions of gcc, icc, clang, arm-whatever, msvc) leading to the same (stringified) result in all cases. The same thing without stringification was rejected as an error with some of the compilers, so I might invest some more time to find whether there is a standard behavior or just a conjunction of implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> What is "the last token of the first argument" and what is "the first token of the second"?

The lexical elements of the C preprocessor are well defined; they are listed in the standard in section 6.4 (and again in Appendix A).  Preprocessing tokens may be a *header-name*, an *identifier*, a *pp-number*, a c*haracter-constant*, a *string-literal*, a *punctuator*, or individual non-whitespace characters that are none of these.  (There's also a "placemarker token" that theoretically could come into play; these are temporary tokens that come into play when a parameter mentioned in a replacement list is matched to an argument consisting of no tokens, but here that does not apply).

Specifically, `cat(1,2)` consists of six tokens; identifer `cat`, punctuator `(`, pp-number `1`, punctuator `,`, pp-number `2`, and punctuator `)`.  `3` is a pp-number.

`cat(cat(1,2),3)` in this context is a macro invocation with two arguments; the first being `cat(1,2)`, and the second being `3`.

The first stage in evaluating a macro is argument substitution.  During this phase, any parameter mentioned in the replacement list is replaced with the corresponding argument after it is fully evaluated, *unless* the parameter in the replacement list is being stringified (preceded by `#`) or participating in a paste (either followed by or preceded by `##`).  In this case, `x` and `y` both participate in a paste, so argument substitution does not occur.

After argument substitution, stringification and pasting occur in an unspecified order.  Since in this case we have a paste operator, we perform pasting.  During pasting, the tokens in the arguments replace the corresponding parameters in the replacement list; then `##` is deleted and the *preceding* token (in this case the punctuator `)`) is concatenated with the *following* token (in this case the pp-number `3`).  The standard specifies that if the result is not a valid preprocessing token, behavior is undefined.  That applies in this case; `)3` is not a valid preprocessing token (it's none of the seven things mentioned above), so the result is undefined.

> Maybe there is a mistake in K&R

The original phrasing is okay (though I'm not sure what exactly a "token string" is in this context).  This might just be a phrasing issue; there's two statements:

1. "Thus it produces the token string cat  (  1  ,  2  )3"
2. ")3 (the catenation of the last token of the first argument with the first token of the second) is not a legal token"

...joined with an "and".  The subject of the second statement is ")3".  I'm not sure how to read your proposed replacement (K&R is meaning to say that `)3` isn't a valid preprocessing token).